# awk to extract lines based on Date range:

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to extract the line items, if the date range between `25-mar-2015 to 05-may-2015` from second field `($2)` . 
Date column is not sorted and each files contain millions of records.

Inputs.gz

```
Des,DateInfo,Amt,Loc,Des2
abc,02-dec-2014,10,def,xyz
abc,20-apr-2015,25,def,xyz
abc,14-apr-2015,40,def,xyz
abc,17-mar-2014,55,def,xyz
abc,24-nov-2011,70,def,xyz
abc,13-may-2015,85,def,xyz
abc,30-sep-2008,100,def,xyz
abc,20-jan-2014,115,def,xyz
abc,04-may-2015,130,def,xyz
abc,25-nov-2013,145,def,xyz
abc,29-mar-2015,55,def,xyz
```

I have tried like below command and in-complete :

```
function getDate(date) {
    split(date, a, "-");
    return mktime(a[3] " " sprintf("%02i",(index("janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec", a[2])+2)/3) " " a[1] " 00 00 00")
}

BEGIN {FS=","}

{ if ( getDate($2)>=getDate(25-mar-2015) && getDate($2)<=getDate(05-may-2015) ) print $0 }
```

Expected Output:

```
abc,20-apr-2015,25,def,xyz
abc,14-apr-2015,40,def,xyz
abc,04-may-2015,130,def,xyz
abc,29-mar-2015,55,def,xyz
```

Please suggest ... I dont have perl & python access.

Comment: The expression `getDate(25-mar-2015)` provides -1990 to `getDate` because you don't have a variable `mar` so it evaluates to 0.  Enclose that in quotes: `getDate("25-mar-2015")` and you might be in with a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function getDate(date,  a) {
    split(date, a, /-/)
    return mktime(a[3]" "(index("janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec",a[2])+2)/3" "a[1]" 0 0 0")
}

BEGIN {
    FS=","
    beg = getDate("25-mar-2015")
    end = getDate("05-may-2015")
}

{ cur = getDate($2) }

NR>1 && cur>=beg && cur<=end

$ awk -f tst.awk  file
abc,20-apr-2015,25,def,xyz
abc,14-apr-2015,40,def,xyz
abc,04-may-2015,130,def,xyz
abc,29-mar-2015,55,def,xyz
```